# Is it possible to call a block completion handler from another function in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, block, objective-c-blocks

I have a custom UIView with a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to it. The gesture recognizer calls a method called hide() to remove the view from the superview as such:

```
func hide(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let customView = sender.view as? UICustomView{
        customView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The UICustomView also has a show() method that adds it as a subview, as such:

```
func show(){
    // Get the top view controller
    let rootViewController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController!!
    // Add self to it as a subview
    rootViewController.view.addSubview(self)
}
```

Which means that I can create a UICustomView and display it as such:

```
let testView = UICustomView(frame:frame) 
testView.show() // The view appears on the screen as it should and disappears when tapped
```

Now, I want to turn my show() method into a method with a completion block that is called when the hide() function is triggered. Something like:

```
testView.show(){ success in
    println(success) // The view has been hidden
}
```

But to do so I would have to call the completion handler of the show() method from my hide() method. 
Is this possible or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are implementing the `UICustomView`, all you need to do is store the 'completion handler' as part of the `UICustomView` class.  Then you call the handler when `hide()` is invoked.

```
class UICustomView : UIView {
   var onHide: ((Bool) -> ())?

   func show (onHide: (Bool) -> ()) {
     self.onHide = onHide
     let rootViewController: UIViewController = ...
     rootViewController.view.addSubview(self)
   }

   func hide (sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let customView = sender.view as? UICustomView{
        customView.removeFromSuperview()
        customView.onHide?(true)
    }
}
```

Of course, every `UIView` has a lifecycle: `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear`, etc.  As your `UICustomView` is a subclass of `UIView` you could override one of the lifecycle methods:

```
class UICustomView : UIView {
  // ...

  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidDisappear (animated)
     onHide?(true)
  }
}
```

You might consider this second approach if the view might disappear w/o a call to `hide()` but you still want `onHide` to run.